# CMake Linker FLAGS for gcc : /usr/bin/ar: -v: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake

I try to build my archive using linux gcc and got this error:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ar: -v: No such file or directory
> ```

I can't understand how to give linker flags for gcc makefiles

```
add_library(libMyExample STATIC  ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
    
    target_include_directories(libMyExample PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
    set_target_properties(libMyExample PROPERTIES 
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${LIB_DIR}$<0:>"
        STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS  -v
        PREFIX ""
    )
```

If I delete `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS  -v`, it's ok.

Comment: Why would you want to pass `-v` option? What would `-v` mean? (display version?) It's `-V` or `-v`? You have `-V` in the title, and `-v` in the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter neither flag works, and why I do that? because I want to . What meen V or v or any other see here   https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar-cmdline.html

Comment: @HaykPoghosyan: "because I want to" - So you have achieved what do you want and have passed `-V` parameter to `ar`. But it seems that resulted parameters list is incorrect for the archiver. You could build the project with `make VERBOSE=1` and examine exact command line which is executed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: OK it looks like    `/usr/bin/ar qc mylib.a -v obj1.o obj2.o`
but I want it to be  `/usr/bin/ar     -qc -v    mylib.a  obj1.o obj2.o`
or better if    `/usr/bin/ar     -r -v    mylib.a  obj1.o obj2.o`

Comment: For changing `-qc` modifier you probably need to change the complete archiver rule, which is stored in the variable [CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY.html). For find out how this variable looks like, you could google for that variable. Or just print that variable in your project (`message("${CMAKE_C_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY}"`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thank you very mutch. I used CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE , by overriding it  ```SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -r <LINK_FLAGS> <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")``` and it workes